# Как использовать NTLM авторизацию на почтовом сервере Echange без ввода пароля

Tags: java, exchange, ews

Использую `ews-java-api` для создания почтового клиента, не смог найти пример кода, который бы использовал текущего авторизованного пользователя windows для авторизации на почтовом сервере. По безопасности нельзя хранить ни в каком виде имя пользователя и пароля. Схема OAuth не подойдет, т.к как там тоже нужно хранить ключ приложения и еще кучу всего и получать секретный токен. Видел что советуют использовать `GSS-API`, но не понял как прикрутить. Пробовал создавать `WebCredentials` через пустой конструктор, по идеи он должен был взять дефолтного пользователя и пароль, но не сработало. Буду благодарен за пример. Пока работает только такой вариант:

```
public EWSService() throws Exception {
    emailUser = TestProperties.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("email.user");
    emailUserDomain = TestProperties.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("email.user.domain");
    emailPassword = TestProperties.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("email.password");
    emailURL = TestProperties.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("email.ewsservice.url");


    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(emailUser, emailPassword, emailUserDomain);
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.setUrl(new URI(emailURL));
}
```